# SMTP Mail Not Working ON Server Working Fine On Localhost

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i am using smtp latest files and check all the solution availble on net, My SMTP php mail working on localhost not working on server my server's web mail working Fine.First of all i am inserting data into my database then those data i want to sent admin email id my data are inserting in database also mail sending working fine on localhost but given error on server it give's failed to connect with server. i contact with my hosting server support forum but they are saying this your code problem
Here is my PHP Code

```
 <?php
   if(isset($_POST['Isubmit'])){
   $rname= $_POST['Iname'];
   $remail= $_POST['Iemail'];
   $rcontact= $_POST['Icontact'];
   $rmessage= $_POST['Icomment'];
   $rcourse= $_POST['Icourse'];
    $date=date("Y-m-d");
 $sql=mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO enquiry(`NAME`,`EMAIL_ID`,`MOBILE_NO`,`COMMENT`,`SUBJECT`,`IS_DELETED`,`DATE`)VALUES('".$rname."','".$remail."','".$rcontact."','".$rmessage."','".$rcourse."','1','".$date."')");

//Mail Send Code


 $ToEmail = 'admin@gmail.com'; 
 $EmailSubject = 'Site contact form'; 
 $MESSAGE_BODY = "Dear Sir/Mam,"."\n" ."\n"."New Contact Details are - "."\n"."\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Full Name: ".$rname."\n"."\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$remail."\n"."\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Phone: ".$rcontact."\n"."\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Message: ".$rmessage."\n"."\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Course: ".$rcourse."\n"."\n";
 //SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don'thave access to that date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
       require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
      //Create a new PHPMailer instance
     $mail = new PHPMailer;
    //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
    $mail->isSMTP();
   //Enable SMTP debugging // 0 = off (for production use)
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
 //Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
  $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
//Set the hostname of the mail server
  $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
   //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
             $mail->Port = 465;
    //Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
       $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
   //Whether to use SMTP authentication
     $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
      $mail->Username = "username@gmail.com";//"lino.cspace@gmail.com";
   //Password to use for SMTP authentication
    $mail->Password = "yourpassword";//"lino@123";
      //Set who the message is to be sent from
       $mail->setFrom('admin@gmail.com', 'Admin');
       $mail->addAddress($ToEmail);
      //Set the subject line
        $mail->Subject = 'Enquiry Mail';
       $mail->Body = $MESSAGE_BODY;//'this is test msg on 25-jun.';
       if(!$mail->Send()) {
         echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
           echo "Message sent!<br>";
          }
       }
```

Comment: Would you be kind and explain us what is the connection between your question and MySQL? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Enable smtp debugging

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
```

OR

```
 $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

Then the error info will give you more info on the error

```
if (!$mail->Send())
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
    echo "Message sent!<br>";
}
```

Comment: The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO server name
CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
CLIENT -> SERVER: aHJkcHJlc3RpZ2Vwb2ludEBnbWFpbC5jb20=
CLIENT -> SERVER: cHJlc3RpZ2Vwb2ludEAxMjM=
SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Both Error Sequentially Show on Different Two Server

Comment: https://www.google.com/settings/u/1/security/lesssecureapps
https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity?hl=en&pli=1

Comment: also use those and setup aii but didn't get success

Comment: Then there is a chance that your ISP has firewall that blocks SMTP traffic. Please talk to your ISP/Hosting support team